# six-dimensional arrays in Eigen

Tags: eigen3

I am new to coding. I am trying to write a computational code using Eigen library. I want to know how can I make and initialize a 6-dimensional array in Eigen like:

```
FF(n0, n1, n2, n3, n4, n5)
```

Regards.

Comment: Do you mean a 6D tensor or a 6x1 vector? In the later case, you can fill it with `FF << n0, n1, n2, n3, n4, n5;`.

Comment: not a tensor, but a six-dimensional array with different rows * cols * slices etc.. like in plain C++ case: `FF[n0][n1][n2][n3][n4][n5] ` Here n0, n1, n2 related to x, y, and z-coordinates in a Cartesian sytem whereas n3, n4 and n5 are basis vector each of a size of 3 i.e. `n3=n4=n5 =3`.

Comment: @CodeLearner How is what you describe different from a tensor?

Comment: @chtz, yes Tensors may be a good option. is there any way that I can define arrays rather than 6-D to 2-D like: `FF[A][B]` where `A = n0*n1*n2` and `B = n3*n4*n5`. The definition may be easy but how to loop/indexing through.